# How to dump flash memory from unbootable Android Operating System of Galaxy Tab A

Tags: android, memory, bootloader, recovery

**I need absolutely to recover data stored on flash memory (dumping internal memory).**
I don't know if it may boot normally because the main problem is there is no more video display to help to diagnostic (no video and no LED to feedback). It means I am not able to change tablet configuration such as Mass storage settings, connection to computer settings, developers USB debugging settings, OEM unlock settings and so on.

Reference:

> **Samsung Galaxy Tab A 9.7 (SM-T550/T555 OF mother board, 2016 version)**
>
> I'm working on **Linux Ubuntu 18.04**

I think I succeed to boot "Mass Storage mode" and to boot "Download mode" by using keys volume down + central button + power button, because when it is plugged to my computer, I noticed a change occured with "dmesg" output and "lsusb" output (see logs below).
Consequently, I think my tab is still alive and a solution to retrieve my data is still possible.

I tried a lot of web advises but I am still blocked : adb, fastboot, heimdall, jmtpfs, mtp-client... nothing works (traces are below).

- Do you think, I can do something with the "Attached scsi devices"
  automatically detected by my computer:  "CD-ROM sr0",  "generic sg2
  type 5",  "generic sg3 type 0".
- Do you think, I can use a serial UART
  console to explore the device?
- The main question is: Do you know if there is a way to entirely control a tab from an external computer, connected with micro USB cable.

If it allows to help, I will be ready to flash a custom bootloader specialized to recovery.

---

**Mass Storage mode**

lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04e8:685b Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (mass storage mode)
```

dmesg output:

```
[Nov 9 17:50] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[  +0,157812] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=685b, bcdDevice= 3.10
[  +0,000008] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000005] usb 1-5: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 49dca9f70e4c53d2
[  +0,000938] usb-storage 1-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0,002892] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-5:1.0
[  +1,007634] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            SAMSUNG  File-Stor Gadget 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  +0,000733] scsi 5:0:0:1: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  File-Stor Gadget 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  +0,001277] sr 5:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[  +0,002037] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x cd/rw tray
[  +0,000007] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[  +0,000613] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  +0,000224] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[  +0,000532] sd 5:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  +0,004911] sd 5:0:0:1: Power-on or device reset occurred
[  +0,002433] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

**After booting in Download mode**

lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (Download mode)
```

dmesg output:

```
[ +18,232055] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  +0,156784] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=685d, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  +0,000008] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0,000005] usb 1-5: Product: MSM8960
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Sasmsung
```

---

**Others attempts and configurations**

In Mass Storage mode, I tried to mount sdc device but an error occurred:

```
mount -o rw /dev/sdc /tmp/media
mount: /tmp/media: no medium found on /dev/sdc.
```

lsblk command show me a rom partition.

```
#lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

#lsblk -S
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL             REV TRAN
[...]
sr0  5:0:0:0    rom  SAMSUNG  File-Stor Gadget 0001 usb
```

---

From ADB (in both mode):

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
 
# adb devices
List of devices attached

# adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

---

From Fastboot (in both mode):

```
#fastboot --version
fastboot version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/fastboot

#fastboot list
< waiting for any device >
```

---

From heimdall with gitlab master branch last build version, with or whithout resume option, it fails.

Heimdall tool results in Mass Storage mode:

```
# ./heimdall detect
ERROR: Failed to detect compatible download-mode device
```

Heimdall tool results in Downlaod mode:

```
./heimdall print-pit --verbose --no-reboot --resume
Heimdall v1.4.2

Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "Sasmsung"
           Product: "MSM8960"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 04E8:685D
         bcdDevice: 0100
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 82
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 01
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Beginning session...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst receiving bulk transfer. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst receiving bulk transfer. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst receiving bulk transfer. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst receiving bulk transfer. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst receiving bulk transfer. Retrying...
ERROR: libusb error -7 whilst receiving bulk transfer.
Releasing device interface...
```

---

I added new udev rule:

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", SYSFS{idProduct}=="685d", MODE="0666"

sudo service udev restart
```

---

With Mass Storage mode, abnormal event occured when I pushed the tab power button.
I think my system tried to open the MTP device but it failed (see following dmesg output):

```
----> I push and release power button:
[ +26,196370] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 12

[ +13,591551] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[  +0,158256] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860, bcdDevice= 4.00
[  +0,000008] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000005] usb 1-5: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[  +0,000005] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  +0,000003] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 49dca9f70e4c53d2
[  +2,030173] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 13
[Nov 9 18:53] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[  +0,157760] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=685b, bcdDevice= 3.10
[  +0,000009] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000005] usb 1-5: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 49dca9f70e4c53d2
[  +0,000939] usb-storage 1-5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0,000410] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-5:1.0
[  +1,017966] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            SAMSUNG  File-Stor Gadget 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  +0,001356] scsi 5:0:0:1: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  File-Stor Gadget 0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  +0,001555] sr 5:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[  +0,002676] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x cd/rw tray
[  +0,000644] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  +0,001648] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[  +0,000266] sd 5:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  +0,003360] sd 5:0:0:1: Power-on or device reset occurred
[  +0,003040] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

And then a popup window appeared:

> "Error: Unable to open MTP device "[usb:001,013]""

---

**Damage cause**:

Last week, when I plugged my tab on a battery charger for a night (5V continu 2A), I noticed a heat problem at "good-morning".  I directly unplugged it because it was to hot and I let it cooled. Then, nothing happens when I tried to turn it on (no signal).

Firstly, I tried to fix the problem by replacing the battery but nothing changed (-20€).
Then, I tried to fix by replacing Micro USB/charger Dock Port but nothing changed too (-10€).

I did some voltage measures to analyse problem source: When power supply is delivered to µUSB connector, if LCD screen connector is plugged to motherboard then battery voltage falls from 4.17V to 2.20V and an important heat increases on screen's bottom (closed to front push button). But if LCD screen connector is no plugged, battery voltage is not disturbed (4.17V).

So, I think damage comes from LCD screen and it is broken. I don't want to change it because it costs almost a new tab full price (150€).

Comment: Yes, I succeed to get PIT file from Heimdall software but the main developper said it is not possible to dump memory because Loke software on samsung device cannot ...  github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/issues/402 and github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/issues/97 . Perhaps ODIN on Windows can do it ? https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=747659

Answer (score 0):

**Apply the following procedure to recover your data** when your LCD screen is down (I think it works too if your screen is completely destroyed and nothing can be displayed).

**1) Install TeamWin recovery image** to boot with (see https://twrp.me/Devices/ and download your recovery image or in my case https://www.phonandroid.com/forum/threads/tuto-installer-le-twrp-recovery-sur-samsung-galaxy-tab-a-9-7-sm-t550-sm-t555.132143/)
For that case, you have to boot in Download mode. And then, you can use Heimdall on Linux and Odin3 on Windows (Windows Samsung USB drivers are necessary).
Once installed, shutdown your device (or disconnect it).

**2) Connect your device USB to PC**. Take care to use a short USB cable and a new one with data line is preferred (not only power externals lines).

**3) Then, boot your device in recovery mode** by multiple keys pressed. From your system PC, control "dmesg" logs in order to watch a new usb device connected 
(see http://www.aidewindows.net/materiel/android-recovery.php#fastboot).

Because you are blinded, take care of no recovery mode boots:

> - Normal boot is wrong [(Volume-) + Power]:
>     New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
> - Download boot is wrong [(Volume+) + Power]:
>     New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860 and then
>     New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=685b

For Recovery mode [Home+(Volume+)+Power], correct sequence is:

> New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=d001 and then
>   New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee2

Right sequence from dmesg:

```
[ +21,247451] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 21
[  +8,201135] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
[  +0,157917] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=d001, bcdDevice= 3.10
[  +0,000009] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 49dca9f70e4c53d2
[  +0,482157] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 22
[  +0,308378] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 23 using ehci-pci
[  +0,157776] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee2, bcdDevice= 3.10
[  +0,000008] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0,000005] usb 1-5: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
[  +0,000004] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  +0,000003] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 49dca9f70e4c53d2
[Nov16 17:01] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 23 using ehci-pci
[  +0,292166] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 23 using ehci-pci
```

Moreover, to control usb communication, I used "watch lsusb" to verify detected usb mode.

> Bus 001 Device 023: ID 18d1:4ee2 Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug)

**4) Then, use "adb devices" command to detect your device** and its recovery state (see http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/328-ubuntu-trusty-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb)
Note: To don't use administration privilege with adb commands, add rules in your system file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules.

**5) Then, use qtadb to explore your data directly** on file system of your device by using graphical GUI. If you prefer using command line, use "adb shell" command to explore device file system by hands.

> ```
> $ adb shell
> ~ # ls -al
> drwxr-xr-x   22 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 .
> drwxr-xr-x   22 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 ..
> drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 boot
> drwxrwx---    8 system   cache         4096 Oct 31  2018 cache
> lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     shell           13 Jan  1  1970 charger -> /sbin/healthd
> drwxrwx--x   59 system   system        4096 Nov 16 17:03 data
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2976 Jan  1  1970 default.prop
> drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root         13760 Jan  6  2015 dev
> drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 etc
> drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 external_sd
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root         15038 Jan  1  1970 file_contexts
> -rw-r-----    1 root     shell         1518 Jan  1  1970 fstab.qcom
> -rwxr-x---    1 root     shell       680916 Jan  1  1970 init
> -rwxr-x---    1 root     root          3125 Jan  1  1970 init.rc
> -rwxr-x---    1 root     shell          111 Jan  1  1970 init.recovery.service.rc
> -rwxr-x---    1 root     shell         1323 Jan  1  1970 init.recovery.usb.rc
> -rwxr-x---    1 root     shell          393 Jan  1  1970 init.recovery.vold_decrypt.rc
> drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 license
> drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 oem
> dr-xr-xr-x  164 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 proc
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          3350 Jan  1  1970 property_contexts
> drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 recovery
> drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 res
> drwx------    2 root     root             0 Aug  7  2016 root
> drwxr-x---    2 root     shell            0 Nov 16 16:00 sbin
> drwxrwx---    0 media_rw media_rw         0 Nov 16 17:03 sdcard
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           703 Jan  1  1970 seapp_contexts
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root            70 Jan  1  1970 selinux_version
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root        144648 Jan  1  1970 sepolicy
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          9769 Jan  1  1970 service_contexts
> drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 sideload
> dr-xr-xr-x   12 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 sys
> drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 system
> drwxrwxr-x    2 root     shell           80 Nov 16 17:07 tmp
> drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 twres
> -rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4726 Jan  1  1970 ueventd.rc
> drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root             0 Jan  6  2015 usb-otg
> ```

**6) Finally, use "adb pull command" to retrieve your data** from your device to your computer You can pull files and folders and a nice download percentage will be displayed. I used "adb pull /sdcard ." command.

7) Now, it is finished. I have recover my data. 
Before, to get rid of your device, I advise you to destroy all user data on memory. So, as a minimum, there is some binary program available to remove files (folder path /sbin/). If not, you can push them to the device with adb push command. You can use "rm" command to delete data. 
Drastically, you can also logically destroy your partition.

To find out what partition a file belongs to and to erase multiple times with ramdom data:

```
~ # df -h /sdcard/
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/mmcblk0p28
                         11.1G      8.2G      2.8G  74% /data
~ # for n in `seq 7`; do dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p28 bs=8b conv=n
otrunc; echo "Done $n/7"; done
```